# Java Huffman Tree

Tags: java, tree, huffman-code

I'm trying to implement printing a huffman tree but with the code represented (1s and 0s). So far I have this, but it doesn't do what I want. I can print a tree, but no code. The input is a frequency table.

I expect the output to be the binary tree (formatted however, it doesn't need to be perfect) and the huffman code itself for each symbol.

I have another method to print the code, but I can't get it to work in the context I want. Here is the tree printing code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node parent;
    char text;
    int frequency;

    public Node(char textIn, int frequencyIn) {
        text = textIn;
        frequency = frequencyIn;
    }

    public Node(int frequencyIn) {
        text = ' ';
        frequency = frequencyIn;
    }

    public int compareTo(Node n) {
        if (frequency < n.frequency) {
            return -1;
        } else if (frequency > n.frequency) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void printFromPreOrder(Node n, String dashes) {
        // print with colon if leaf node
        if (n.text != ' ') {
            System.out.println(dashes + n.frequency);
        } else {
            System.out.println(dashes + n.frequency);
        }

        // Start recursive on left child then right
        if (n.left != null) {
            printFromPreOrder(n.left, dashes + "-");
        }
        if (n.right != null) {
            printFromPreOrder(n.right, dashes + "-");
        }
    }

    // Returns root node to pass to printFromPreOrder
    public static Node makeHuffmanTree(int frequencies[], char text[]) {
        PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            Node n = new Node(text[i], frequencies[i]);
            queue.add(n);
        }
        Node root = null;

        while (queue.size() > 1) {
            Node least1 = queue.poll();
            Node least2 = queue.poll();
            Node combined = new Node(least1.frequency + least2.frequency);
            combined.right = least1;
            combined.left = least2;
            least1.parent = combined;
            least2.parent = combined;
            queue.add(combined);
            // Keep track until we actually find the root
            root = combined;
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```

Here is the code to generate the 1s and 0s:

```
public void traverseDepthFirst(Node node, String code) {
    // only proceed if tree is not null
    if (node != null) {
        // compute the index of the symbol in S
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (S[i] == node.text) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        // store the current code in the code array at the index of the
        // symbol
        this.code[index] = code;
        // traverse left
        this.traverseDepthFirst(node.left, code + "1");
        // traverse right
        this.traverseDepthFirst(node.right, code + "0");
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int frequencies[] = {3, 1, 2};
    char text[] = {'x', 'y', 'z'};
    Node root = Node.makeHuffmanTree(frequencies, text);
    Node.printFromPreOrder(root, "");
    Huffman.traverseDepthFirst(root, "");
}
```

Comment: Could you please include in the question the output you are expecting? That'd be helpful in understanding what you mean by printing the code.

Comment: Info about output is added

Comment: Ok then I'm not sure I see the problem. Can't you just call the method that generates the codes in `printFromPreorder`?

Comment: I'm not in front of it right now, but I think the issue is that I can't call a non-static instance from a static method (printFromPreorder is static and traverseDepthFirst is static)

Comment: Anyone have any tips?

Comment: `printFromPreorder` should not be static. Make it an ordinary member of `Node` and remove the first argument (which is now just `this`). Then you should be able to call the method to get the code.

Comment: It's not printFromPreorder I'm having issues with. It's `traverseDepthFirst`. I tried making it a member of `Node`, but in its current form I get the non-static method error when calling it from main. I tried making it static, but then it gives me errors because the variables like 'n' 's' and 'node are not static.